# C# Lock Statement

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im going to use the C# lock statement and im wondering if i call a function while inside a lock, and that function also does a lock on the same object will the program freeze?

For example:

```
Object object;

public void f0()
{
   f1(object);
}

public void f1(Object obj1)
{
   lock (obj1) {
       f2(obj1);
   }
}

public void f2(Object obj2)
{
  lock(obj2) {
      /// do operations using obj2
  }
 }
```

Here function f0 calls function f1 which does a lock, inside that lock it calls f2 which also does a lock. So will the program freeze in f2 waiting for the object locked in f1?

I have a big program with functions calling each other passing objects around, and i need to lock some objects, but it may happen that the function i call may also lock the same object, so it may get locked twice, causing possible deadlock.

It may be difficult to know if the same objects gets passed around and may end up getting locked twice.

Also my program has multi-threading and multiple classes.

Also what if one thread gets an exception inside the lock, will it somehow unwind and fix itself?

Anybody knows the proper way to do this? I have a big program so before i start changing everything i decide i better find out the proper way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: It seems strange to me to ask "Will this code freeze?" when you could just run it and find out.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Your comment is a little off when you said, *"/// do operations using obj2"* did you mean "/// do operations while there's a lock on obj2"? Because the object you're locking on shouldn't be something that you need to do anything with, except use for a lock.

Comment: I didnt try it, i want to find out the "proper" way to do it before i start changing everything!

Comment: Rufus, so im not supposed to do anything with the object except lock it? For example i have an object that points to MySQL database (has all the database stuff to access the database in there) so I just do i lock on that object and then use it to query the database inside the lock, so that is not the correct way? I thought you can lock on any object, so that nobody else uses that object while you are using it?

Comment: The lock object is only used to *aquire a lock* before doing something with some other common object. The code that attempts to get the lock will wait until it can get a lock before proceeding. This way, multiple threads could be writing to the same file, for example, if they all wrap their code with `lock (lockObject) { }` (where `lockObject` is the same, static object).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Monitor` (which is used by the `lock` statement under the covers) is reentrant, so it's technically ok for the same thread to lock on an object multiple times. The lock will be released when the outer `lock` scope completes. However, reentrant locks are difficult to reason about and should be avoided unless you have no other option.

Deadlocks do not occur due to reentrant locks. They occur when you take out locks on multiple objects while some other thread locks the same objects in a different order.

Comment: is it ok to lock the same object im using, or do i have to create a dedicated object just for the purposes of locking (like in the code above)?  I dont see why i need a dedicated locking object because the object im using is derived from "object" just like a dedicated locking object, so why create another object?

Comment: @PaulMan, the rule of thumb is that you should not leak the objects you lock on to the outside world. If you're storing the lock object reference in a `readonly` private field then it's okay to lock on, and you're avoiding an extra field (and allocation) in doing so. But you better be absolutely certain you don't leak that reference (via a public/internal property getter for example).

Comment: If the object is publicly accessible then you have to be a lot more careful because there's a chance that someone else will take out a lock on it when you don't expect (and good luck debugging your code when that happens). In that case you absolutely need an extra, private object reference to lock on.

Comment: So, to summarise, the *safe* advice is to have a dedicated object (whose accessibility you tightly control) to lock on. Then you don't have to spend the brainpower trying to work out whether there's any chance of leaking a reference to it (right now or *in the future* when someone comes and changes your code unexpectedly).

Answer (score 0):

Locking the object makes it simply a single threaded code which can be used to prevent mixups or premature calculations (this is only an example).

Comment: Using locks does not make it single threaded, though it would act that way if all threads happen to be trying to use the lock at the same time (which is not usually the case).

Comment: on the use of lock it behaves like a single thread since it literally locks out other threads that use the "locked" code. it's although mostly used on multi threaded to make the program impertinent as critical code.

Comment: yep. in fact it's *only* used for multi-threaded applications. I was just pointing out that the application only behaves as a single thread during moments when *all* threads are trying to lock the same object at the same time. Otherwise, any threads that aren't trying to lock the object will continue to run even though some other thread has a lock.

Comment: that's true but it doesn't need to be locked from other places to get the wished behavior but it works in all the conditions to lock out other code that tries to access it. but I really appreciate the explanation you gave I didn't think of that.